# Can I get the SUM of td value and input value inside another td with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a table which is contains a td values and input inside another td which is contains a value too.

I want to get the sum of the td value and the other td that contain the input.

This is the code but it doesn't work perfectly:

```js
let gross = 0;
$(".total").each(function() {
  gross += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
document.getElementById('gross_amount').innerHTML = gross;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>Salary</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Hazem</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td class="total">50.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td><input class="total" type="text" value="60.00" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <div id="gross_amount"></div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because one element is a `td` and the other is an `input`, and only `input` elements have a `value` property to be read by `val()`.

To fix the issue you can detect the type of element using `tagName` and then retrieve either the `text()` or `val()` based on that:

```js
let gross = 0;
$(".total").each(function() {
  let $el = $(this);
  gross += parseFloat(this.tagName == 'INPUT' ? $el.val() : $el.text());
});
$('#gross_amount').text(gross.toFixed(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>Salary</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Hazem</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td class="total">50.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td><input class="total" type="text" value="60.00" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="gross_amount"></div>
```

Note that the `#gross_amount` div needs to be outside the `<table>` element for your HTML to be valid. Also, if you've loaded jQuery then you might as well keep the code consistent and use it to update the `#gross_amount` element too.

Comment: Man I'm really appreciate it thank you so much. This is worked for me either, now I got the point thanks a lot.